# jquery connected-lists prevent dropping on specified list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have modified example connected-lists from jquery site http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists below:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <style>
    .connectedSortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 2.5em; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
    .connectedSortable li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; width: 120px; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="connectedSortable last">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

I need to prevent dropping to **ul.last**
Or in other words I need to prevent dropping into list to specific list if exists special condition.(connectedSortable styles should stay)

http://jsfiddle.net/Fdpyr/4/

Is there any ability to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// If you want a specific ul to get sortable you can use this

 $(function() {
    $( ".connectedSortable:eq(0)" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

or If you want last ul not to be sortable use it like this:

```
  $(function() {
    $( ".connectedSortable:not(:last)" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Hope this works for you the way you need...